# How to make Selenium test run both on local and remote server with Python Django?

Tags: python, django, testing, selenium

Many Selenium test examples begin like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.self.driver.get("some hardcoded url")
```

Is there way to avoid hardcoding urls into the test and somehow retreive domain name from the environment the test was launched in?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go the environment route, here is how to do it:

```
import os
print os.environ['HOME']
```

Another option is to have different configuration files for different servers and parse them while initializing your test harness, although if you have 100 test files, probably it is suboptimal to parse the config for each one of them.

Comment: It prints "home/sashko". I ment url, not filesystem home.

Comment: Yes, this was just an example. Do (on bash)
export FOO_URL="http://bringvictory.com"
and then you can access it via os.environ("FOO_URL")

Comment: I am sorry, but I realy do not understand how this `Do (on bash) export FOO_URL="bringvictory.com";` would affect tests launched remotely if I type some command on my bash console locally. Or should I write such a command in some script file?